# Open-source virtual machine apps supporting larger VRAM than 256 MB

Tags: software-recommendation, virtualization, v-ram

I have tried Virtual Box  running Windows 10 with it, but all i get is 256 MB of video memory, while I have a 4 GB VRAM video card.

When I try with VM Ware the video memory is increased to about 3GB and Windows runs much faster and better.

VM WARE cost around 190 GPB and that's a lot.

Are you aware of any better open-source solutions ?
Is there like another virtualization tool that runs smooth as VM ware but free or cheaper

Comment: The virtual graphics driver from guest additions will support part of the RAM on you host graphic card.

Comment: still windows is very slow on Virtual Box after the additions , on the other hand VM ware is super fast with windows. and smooth.